# Windows Store Class Library Embedding a XAML based User Control

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, asp.net-4.5

How can you pre-compile a XAML based user control into the dll?

Something similar to how the Razor Generator works for MVC Views.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There is a Class Library (Windows Store apps) that you can create which can be referenced from your App. However it has to be packaged with your application and can not loaded dynamically on the fly.

Comment: But I would like it to be embedded inside of the dll. So it would always have to be there as seperate XAML file?

Comment: No. The XAML is always embedded in the dll.